# The voltage bias can switch the output light from the same waveguide $a$ to the other waveguide $b$ when the input light is into the waveguide $a$?

Tags: photonics

I am currently studying the textbook *Physics of Photonic Devices, second edition* by Shun Lien Chuang. Chapter **1.4 Overview of the Book** says the following:

> An example of an electrically controlled directional coupler is shown in Fig. 1.15, where the coupling of two parallel waveguides is controlled by a pair of electrodes via the change of the refractive index through the electrooptical effects. The voltage bias can switch the output light from the same waveguide $a$ to the other waveguide $b$ when the input light is into the waveguide $a$.
> [image]

I don't understand this description of figure 1.15. In particular, I find the follow explanation confusing:

> The voltage bias can switch the output light from the same waveguide $a$ to the other waveguide $b$ when the input light is into the waveguide $a$.

Would someone please take the time to explain this?

Comment: Are you asking for help to understand what the text is telling you? or are you asking for somebody to explain how the device works? (The text only says what the device does, it doesn't go into detail about how the device works.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow The former

Comment: To understand how this switch works you have to understand here two unrelated issues in physics: 1.) electro-optical effect. 2.) waveguide coupler. Which one is your problem and what is your question about that?

Comment: @hyportnex Probably both. As I said, I'm particularly interested in a better explanation fo what the author said here: "The voltage bias can switch the output light from the same waveguide $a$ to the other waveguide $b$ when the input light is into the waveguide $a$."

Comment: start here: https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/directional-couplers and note that the purpose of the electro-optic effect is to change the coupling phase by changing the substrate permittivity between the coupled lines.